# IIS - http Runtime Error

Tags: iis

I had already published my site using the IIS Manager.
I successfully can access it with my PC but when my colleagues tried to access it, it says,

HTTP Runtime Error.

Is there something wrong in the config file? How come I can access it with no error? Can anyone help us with this?

Answer (score 1):

> http runtime error
>
> Is not a lot to go by.

What do the windows event logs say?
What is the website, Asp.net or something else?

If it is asp.net, update this setting and post what error they see:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>`